# Remake a file if it has changed

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefile that will produce a file

```
all: build/foo.bin
build/foo.bin: foo.c
   gcc $< -o $@
```

Works great and produces `build/foo.bin` as expected.  If I then do a another `make` it will say `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`.  That's expected.

I then do `rm build/foo.bin && make` and it rebuilds the file. But if I do a `echo "Modified" > build/foo.bin` make doesn't think that anything has changed  `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`.

How can I write the rules of the Makefile to re-create the build/foo.bin if the binary ever gets modified outside of the Makefile?

Answer (score 3):

Make compares timestamps between two files.  If the target file exists and its timestamp is newer than all of the prerequisites' timestamps, then make decides the target is up to date and it doesn't need to do anything.

Make doesn't maintain some kind of database of timestamps on its own: it relies on the filesystem for that.  So make cannot detect when a file changes from what it previously contained.  It can only detect when some *other* file changed after the target file was last updated.

In short, make cannot do what you want it to do, using its standard methods.

If you want to do that you'll have to get complicated and create a way to turn the behavior you want to detect into a file with a timestamp, that make can compare.

One way to do this would be to keep the md5sum of the file in another file, then compare it and update the file only if it's changed.  You can try this (I didn't test it):

```
build/foo.bin: foo.c checksum.out
        gcc $< -o $@
        md5sum $@ > checksum.out
        touch $@

checksum.out: FORCE
        md5sum build/foo.bin > checksum.tmp; cmp $@ checksum.tmp || cp checksum.tmp $@

FORCE: ;
```

Basically, the FORCE is there to require the md5sum check to always run, but then if the checksum doesn't actually change it doesn't update the output file which means that `build/foo.bin` won't be rebuilt (at least not because checksum.out is updated).

Comment: Bleh.  I have a whole tree worth of files that I want to monitor.  I'm going to need to come up with some new strategy.

Comment: Agreed.  Make is not a good tool for knowing if someone changed a file on the disk.  Make is a good tool for knowing if a file is out of date WRT another file and needs to be updated.